# Delete some informations in a json variable with php

Tags: php, json

My problem is that i am parsing an XML file and this file contain some information that i don't want to exporting as JSON data. In my case i want a function that return the json data from the first '[' caratere
this is the php code:

```
    <?php

class XmlToJsonConverter {
    public function ParseXML ($url) {
        $fileContents= file_get_contents($url);
        // Remove tabs, newline, whitespaces in the content array
        $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
        $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
        $myXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
        $json = json_encode($myXml);
        return $json;
    }
}
//Path of the XML file
$url= 'http://www.lequipe.fr/rss/actu_rss_Football.xml';

//Create object of the class
$jsonObj = new XmlToJsonConverter();

//Pass the xml document to the class function
$myjson = $jsonObj->ParseXMl($url);
print_r ($myjson);
?>
```

this is a part of the JSON result :

> {"@attributes":{"version":"2.0"},"channel":{"title":"L'Equipe.fr Actu Football","link":"http://www.lequipe.fr","description":"L'Equipe.fr, Toute l'actualit\u00e9 du football","language":"fr","copyright":"Copyright L'Equipe.fr","pubDate":"Wed, 22 Apr 2015 16:31:08 +0200","image":{"url":"http://www.lequipe.fr/rss/logo_RSS.gif","title":"L'Equipe.fr","link":"http://www.lequipe.fr","width":"119","height":"28"},"item":[{"title":"Foot - Cha

i want that the result start from '['

Thank you

Comment: use xPath to select specific node from xml/html

Comment: i am generating this json to an android application. i must start from the caractere '[' so the android can read it as a JsonArrayObject. i just want to remove all text before the first '[' caractere

Comment: i woud put this string thru regEx with positive lookbehind for(":) and selelced rest from [

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand you !!

Comment: this is a JSON string. Javascript can match a regular expression and select pattern u describe. Google for **regex**

Comment: sorry but this is not the answer of my question !!

Answer (score 1):

Remove every attribute you don't want just before encoding json:

```
public function ParseXML ($url) {
    $fileContents= file_get_contents($url);
    // Remove tabs, newline, whitespaces in the content array
    $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
    $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
    $myXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
    //--------------
    unset($myXml['@attributes']);
    unset($myXml['channel']);
    unset($myXml['image']);
    //--------------
    $json = json_encode($myXml);
    return $json;
}
```

or if you only need the item:

```
public function ParseXML ($url) {
    $fileContents= file_get_contents($url);
    // Remove tabs, newline, whitespaces in the content array
    $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
    $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
    $myXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
    //--------------
    $json = json_encode($myXml['item']);
    return $json;
}
```

Comment: it dosen't work !! it always return all the data !! i tryed the 2 solutions !

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was away for some time and I forgot coming back. Do you still have the problem. I'm not sure why you still saw other attributes but I'm sure both solutions work well. Have you tried tracing the php script? (e.g. print_r($myXml), print_r($json) and then exit; to force quiting)